# Modificar objeto desde boton dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe

necesito ayuda, tengo una web en donde tengo un div oculto y un objeto iframe, dentro de ese iframe tengo un botón que quiero que muestre ese div del html padre, algo así:

```
<body>
<div id="cosa" style="display: none"></div>
<iframe src="contenido/hijo.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

y el hijo html asi:

```
<body>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red" onclick="window.parent.document.getElementById('cosa').style.display='block';"></div>
</body>
```

y no me funciona, como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Tengo entendido que la interacción del documento al iframe y/o viceversa es una característica restringida, dudo mucho que puedas hacer lo que buscas de esta forma, de todas formas voy a seguir esta pregunta a ver si alguien me sorprende

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, espero que alguien tenga la solución

Answer (score 1):

Al final me has dejado con la mosca detrás de la oreja...

Una búsqueda ha bastado para comprobar que es posible, **siempre que sea dentro del mismo dominio.** Como ya te comenté, la interacción entre dominios a través de un iframe no está permitido.

El iframe se puede comunicar con el documento padre mediante mensajes. Estos mensajes funcionan a modo de señal, no emiten nada más que eso, una señal, por lo tanto, lo único que puedes saber es si el iframe está interactuando, pero no puedes enviar ningún mensaje dinámico desde dentro.

Prueba esto en un HTML a parte para probarlo:

### HTML (index)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="afterIframe"></h1>
        <iframe id="com" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
        <button onclick="show()"></button>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Script (index)

```
let iframe = document.getElementById('com');
let text = document.getElementById('afterIframe');

window.onmessage = function(e){
    if (e.data == 'message'){
        text.innerHTML = "Botón del iframe pulsado";
    }
}
```

### Iframe

```
<script>
    function send() {
        window.top.postMessage('message', '*');
    }
</script>
<button onclick="send()">Mostrar</button>
```

Al recibir la señal (mensaje) `message`, el script del index.html responderá con el `innerHTML` al `h1`.

Comment: Como detalle, si quieres usar esto para algo más elaborado, te recomiendo que te mires cosas como Angular, puedes comunicar "páginas" mediante observables. Esto es extremadamente extenso, pero créeme, merece la pena aprenderlo. Si por lo que sea, te interesa la parte de los observables, mírate RxJS, es una pasada.

Comment: muchas gracias, por tu respuesta, si claro, va a ser dentro del mismo dominio, por eso intentaba realizarlo de una forma directa y poder mostrar y ocultar divs, y estos divs tienen textos e imágenes, es la única acción que necesito.

Comment: Entonces genial, tendrás que declarar cada mensaje, pero podrás hacer lo que necesitas. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como válida!

Comment: adicional, intente colocar código html en el text.innerHTML pero al parecer solo permite texto

Comment: creo q no me hice entender, osea, tu solución funsiona, al parecer solo con texto, intente colocar código html en el text.innerHTML o hay q cambiar algo para que incruste html?

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta a parte, hay muchas guías en internet para hacer lo que pides. De todas formas, innerHTML reescribe el contenido de un elemento HTML, no veo qué problema puedas tener si tu sintaxis está bien.

Comment: Prueba con `text.innerHTML = "<h2>Prueba</h2>";`

Answer (score 0):

probé tu código y parece funcionar bien. Agrégale un texto o algún elemento dentro del div para que lo puedas ver.

```
 <body>
<div id="cosa" style="display: none">Texto oculto</div>
<iframe src="contenido/hijo.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

El hijo queda igual

```
<body>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red" onclick="window.parent.document.getElementById('cosa').style.display='block';"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola,  claro en el proyecto real ya tiene algún contenido como img y texto, pero no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @Marcos Rodríguez, encontré lo que necesitaba gracias a ti, hice un pequeño cambio en el código para que hiciera lo que realmente quería...

en el index -->

```
<iframe id="c1" src="contenido/iframe.html"></iframe>

      <div id="cosa1" style="display: none">
      <img src="contenido/img/img.png" style="width: 80%" alt="">
      </div>
      <script>
    let iframe = document.getElementById('c1');
window.onmessage = function(e){
if (e.data == 'message'){
document.getElementById("cosa1").style.display="block";
}
```

}

y en el iframe -->

```
<script>
function send() {
    window.top.postMessage('message', '*');
}
```

Mostrar

y funcionó correctamente, pero ahora me surge otra pregunta, ¿Cómo hago para hacerlo con mas objetos?, es decir, tener otro botón "mostrar" y muestre otro objeto diferente, lo intente pero solo me funciona con el primero, cambie el send(); por send2(); pero no me funciono.